# No implicit conversion of Array into String - Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to get an app up and running on a new machine. May be using a slightly updated version of Ruby (2.3.4 vs 2.3.1) and the Rails version is 5.1.3.

**Here's the migration:**

```
class AddDragAndDropRules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :products, :fixture_location, :string, default: "none"
    add_column :products, :attaches_to, :uuid, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

The issue during `rails db:migrate`.

**Error:**

```
== 20160928162420 AddDragAndDropRules: migrating ==============================
-- add_column(:products, :fixture_location, :string, {:default=>"none"})
   -> 0.0142s
-- add_column(:products, :attaches_to, :uuid, {:array=>true, :default=>[]})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

no implicit conversion of Array into String
/Users/mike/api/db/migrate/20160928162420_add_drag_and_drop_rules.rb:4:in `change'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
/Users/mike/api/db/migrate/20160928162420_add_drag_and_drop_rules.rb:4:in `change'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Anyone able to spot the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else - the project was upgraded to Rails 5.1.3 at some point which is causing UUID array migrations to fail due to a bug.

Issue is here (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30539) and workaround in 5.1.2-5.1.3 is to do this:

```
add_column :products, :attaches_to, :uuid, array: true, default: '{}'
```

Should be fixed in 5.1.4 and above.